# Two separate keys map to a single entry in a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm working on a piece of code that has the objective of being a fast "search engine". I have entries in a file that need to be searchable after reading the whole file in. They need to be searchable by both the name of the entry, and it's offset from the beginning of the file. My problem is one of memory usage since there are millions of entries. Currently I am using two separate std::maps to store the data so that either search term can be specified. This leads to double storage of the data which is what I am trying to reduce.

I've used valgrind massif to find that a major part of the memory usage is the double storage of entries.

Current method of storage:

```
struct entry {
    std::string name;
    uint16_t offset;
    uint16_t size;
    bool isConst;
};

nameSearchMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, entry>(s_entry.name, e_entry));
offsetSearchMap.insert(std::pair<uint16_t, SymInfo>(s_entry.offset, s_entry));
```

Is there a way that I can can make a single map that is searchable by either type of key?

Comment: This sounds like you should be using a database.

Comment: @NathanOliver The data is loaded from a personalized file for each user. This is not a common data set. Additionally, the user can reload files. So the data set can change several times during a single usage.

Comment: I don't say it's the best solution, but how about a [Boost multi-index container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider using

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<entry>>
```

for mapping strings to an entry, and

```
std::map<uint16_t, std::shared_ptr<entry>>
```

Note that by using shared pointers for the value payload (thus using the same `entry` object for both maps), you save the size of a payload. While you pay for two shared pointers, you'll still come out ahead for your specific structure.

[image]

(felt like drawing a diagram. The point, though, is that there is only one `entry` object in memory.)

---

You might also be interested in [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html).

Comment: I did this, except I just used normal pointers instead of shared pointers. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the purpose of shared_ptr is to allow multiple owners of an object for memory management; this means that erasing the entry in both maps will automatically delete the entry.

Answer (score 2):

> They need to be searchable by both the name of the entry, and it's offset from the beginning of the file.

This indicates to me that you can store the data in an array/vector and use maps that map to indices in the array/vector.

```
std::vector<entry> entries;
std::map<std::string, size_t> map1;
std::map<uint16_t, size_t> map2;
```

Comment: This will work, but there is no need for the vector since the structs will be allocated on the heap and standard pointers can be used instead of indices. Is there any benefit to using the vector instead?

Comment: @TheBat, using `std::vector` frees you up from memory allocation and deallocation concerns while providing all the conveniences of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can save three poiner per entry, and avoid entry duplication. But method usable only if insertion is not so often than fetch:

```
std:vector<std::string> names;
std:vector<entry> entries;
std:map<uint16_t,size_t> offset2pos;
```

names and entryes must be sorted identically, so
pos of name equal entry with that name respectively

```
names[pos] == entries[pos].name
```

and map offset2pos can convert offset to pos

```
size_t pos = offset2pos[offset]
```

to convert name to pos use binary search (std::lower_bound)

```
size_t pos = names.begin() - std::lower_bound( names.begin(), names.end(), offset )
```

This technuque good for that cases when insertion is not so often than fetch.
But algoritm is no so trivial, and you need to reassign offset2pos (possible
rebuild) each time you insert one or more elements.

In the answer above You need save per element:

std::string, uint16_t, 2 * Sptr, 4 * Mptr

In the my approuch :

std::string, uint16_t, Sptr, 2 * Mptr

Where:
    Sptr - is smaprt pointer object internal pointer
    Mptr - map binary three node left and right pointer

So 3 pointer per entry is your memory profit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) as follows:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d12964d975910a5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

struct entry {
  std::string name;
  uint16_t offset;
  uint16_t size;
  bool isConst;
};

using namespace boost::multi_index;

using entry_map=multi_index_container<
  entry,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<tag<struct by_name>,member<entry,std::string,&entry::name>>,
    hashed_unique<tag<struct by_offset>,member<entry,uint16_t,&entry::offset>>
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  entry_map m={{"hello",0,10,false},{"hi",1,20,true},{"bye",2,15,false}};
  auto&     name_map=m.get<by_name>();
  auto&     offset_map=m.get<by_offset>();

  std::cout<<"size(\"hello\"): "<<name_map.find("hello")->size<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"size(2): "<<offset_map.find(2)->size<<"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
size("hello"): 10
size(2): 15
```